# When connecting to MongoDB via PHP maximum limit size error appears

Tags: php, mongodb, remote-access, remote-server

I am trying to connect to remote server using this PHP code:

```
if ($mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://root:password#@111.111.111.11:2222'))
  if ($db = $mongo->selectDB("test"))
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'Failed to connect to: 111.111.111.11:2222: send_package: data
>   corruption: the returned size of the reply (759714607) is larger than
>   the maximum allowed size (4194304)' in
>   /var/www/html/mongo/index.php:24 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/mongo/index.php(24):
>   MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://root:...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/mongo/index.php on line 24

Comment: Are you connecting to a right MongoDB port? I've had issues when tried connecting by accident to a memcached chatty protocol port...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command to create ssh tunnel:

> autossh -C -p 22 -l `{name}` -N -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o
>   NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -o ControlMaster=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=password  -L 27018:localhost:27017
>   root@420.213.412.21

It basically created ssh connection tunnel between my local machine and the server with database. Opening port is 27018 and ending port is 27017 which is MongoDB port.

And then for connection parameter in code I used this:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient('localhost:27018');
```

Connecting to opening port of the ssh tunnel.